# how can i display the number of days in a month that i input with two arrays?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop

This is what i'm stuck on, i need to use two arrays, one for months and one for the days in the month. i want to link them so when a user inputs January the text box is filled with the number 31. I've made both arrays but i'm unable to link them. My Prof says i have to use a for each...next statement that uses linear search .. but i cant for the life of me figure it out. I've tried making MonthName(0) = Monthdays(0) but it did nothing. I also need to use String.Compare if the user misspelled something so it tells them the word didn't match. i'm lost. This is my code so far. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim MonthName(11)
        Dim Monthdays(11)
        Dim searchData(11) As Integer

        MonthName(0) = "January"
        MonthName(1) = "February"
        MonthName(2) = "March"
        MonthName(3) = "April"
        MonthName(4) = "May"
        MonthName(5) = "June"
        MonthName(6) = "July"
        MonthName(7) = "August"
        MonthName(8) = "September"
        MonthName(9) = "October"
        MonthName(10) = "November"
        MonthName(11) = "December"

        Monthdays(0) = 31
        Monthdays(1) = 28
        Monthdays(2) = 31
        Monthdays(3) = 30
        Monthdays(4) = 31
        Monthdays(5) = 30
        Monthdays(6) = 31
        Monthdays(7) = 31
        Monthdays(8) = 30
        Monthdays(9) = 31
        Monthdays(10) = 30
        Monthdays(11) = 31

        For i = 0 To searchData.GetUpperBound(0)
            TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(Monthdays)
        Next

        If TextBox1.Text = String.Empty Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invald Entry.", "Error", 
                  MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: use a `For n` loop.  When `MonthName(n)` matches what you are looking for, `n` will also be the index into `MonthDays`.  That is `MonthName(n)` has `MonthDays(n)` days in it. You could also use `Array.IndexOf()` to skip the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For n as Integer = 0 to MonthName.Length - 1
    if MonthName(n) = TextBox1.Text then
         TextBox1.Text = Monthdays(n).ToString()
         Exit For
    end if
next
```

This will loop all MonthNames. If the name matches the text from the textbox, its textx is replaced by corresponding Monthdays.

The `Exit For` statement stops the loop if corresponding monthday was found to avoid unnecessary performance

You may have to rename `TextBox1` to the name of your `TextBox` object.

You should declare your arrays with data types: `Dim MonthName(11) as String` and `Dim Monthdays(11) as Integer`

I hope this helps. I didnt test this code. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The last index in MonthName is MonthName.Length - 1, so the first statement should be `For n As Integer = 0 To MonthName.Length - 1`

Comment: thanks bro your a lifesaver !! i understand it way better now

Answer (score 0):

What your prof said about the `For Each... Next`, was a suggestion? Or a requeriment? Because IMO it would made things more complex.

Anyway, as Plutonix said in the comments, you could use a simple `For n` loop or `Array.IndexOf()` (althought I believe the point is to use loops).

With a `For n`:

```
TextBox2.Text = "" 'Sanity check
For i as Integer = 0 to 11
    If MonthName(i) = TextBox1.Text Then 'If the current Month name equals user input...
        TextBox2.Text = Monthdays(i) '...we get the corresponding days and put them on the TextBox
        Exit For 'We found what we were looking for... no need to continue searching
    End If
Next

If TextBox2.Text = "" Then 'Notify if we didn't find a match
    MessageBox.Show("Invald Entry.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Using `Array.IndexOf()`

```
Dim index as Integer 'define a variable to store the index
index = Array.IndexOf(MonthName, TextBox1.Text) 'We try to find the position of MonthName that equals user input
If index >= 0 Then 'If there was a match, we get the month days of that position
    TextBox2.Text = Monthdays(index)
Else 'if not, notify...
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    MessageBox.Show("Invald Entry.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

As far as I can see, using a `For Each... Next` would require the use of `Array.IndexOf()`, thus making the loop unnecesary.

Hope some of this options help.